# fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory in Yocto

Tags: ssl, openssl, yocto, swupdate

My Yocto sources are on `Warrior` currently and I am in a process of migrating them to `dunfell` so I cloned all the required layers for `dunfell` branch including `meta-swupdate`.

Now, I am trying to generate swupdate image by `bitbake swupdate-image` command for `dunfell` and I am getting errors as given below:

```
    .
    .      
    In file included from /home/panther2/dunfell/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/swupdate/2021.04-r0/git/corelib/verify_signature.c:15:
    /home/panther2/dunfell/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/swupdate/2021.04-r0/git/include/sslapi.h:31:10: fatal error: openssl/bio.h: No such file or directory
       31 | #include <openssl/bio.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    .
    .
    make[2]: *** [core/swupdate.o] Error 1
    /home/panther2/dunfell/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/swupdate/2021.04-r0/git/mongoose/mongoose.c:4473:10: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
     4473 | #include <openssl/ssl.h>
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    .
    .
```

Looks like it is unable to find ssl related header files. Any lead on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no openssl dependency in the swupdate recipe.

Adding `DEPENDS += "openssl"` in a `swupdate_%.bbappend` file helps.

Comment: Yes, I did same thing. Just wanted to check whether that is a right approach or not. My thought on this is, it should be part of `meta-swupdate`.